# Python: Multiprocessor process run from a child?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

Is it possible to run a multiproccessing module from another module that is itself a child. Why? For example I have one process that controls a stepper motor, and another which debounces an RPi input port. The stepper motor stops when the RPi input becomes logic 1 (you guessed it, an end stop microswitch). All this is run from a top level 'user interface'.

I have read all about having to put the 'calling' code in a `__main__` block. Yep, works fine.

Is this just a Windows problem (I am doing first off testing on my PC before porting to actual target, RPi)....

Comment: Yes. It is possible. What actual problem are you having?  Why do you think that "calling" code needs to be put in a "main block", and what exactly *is* a main block?)  (Also what is the antecedent of "this" where you say: 'Is *this* just a Windows problem'?)

Comment: Hi @Gil Hamilton. Yes, sorry, I typed  __main__, and somehow it turned into plain old main. I am an electronics engineer, so please excuse the sloppy use of SW terminology (unless you want to talk ALGOL). I am not sure sure what you are refering to when you say "antecedent". I mean Not RPi (which I take almost universally equates to Linux?), and the repeated statement I find saying add the 'mulitprocessing' code in an   if __name__ == "__main__"   block to stop this (what apears to me to be) strange behaviour of code looping on itself.

Comment: And so it happens again. Underscore, underscore, main, underscore, underscore.

Comment: I still have no clue what you're actually having trouble with. Try providing a [mcve] (yes, with actual code -- it doesn't have to actually run a stepper motor or whatever, just have your sub-process(es) print/sleep/print/sleep or something).

Comment: Also, note you can put a code reference in backticks to protect it from being interpreted as markup. See the edit I made to your question. And if you add code, be sure (after pasting it into the edit box) to highlight the code and press the code sample button, which looks like this: `{}`